# sending one composed text to emails saved in database using laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I have created a form, upon its submission it goes to email id which is stored in Laravels mail function. But I want to send same email to multiple people whose email-id are stored in database. Here is my code:

Routes:

```
Route::get('contactform', 'ClientsController@display1');
Route::post('contactform', 'ClientsController@contact');
```

My controller:

```
public function display(){
    $data = Input::get('agree');
    $count = count ($data);
    if($count){
        return $this->contact( $data,$count);
    }
    else{
        echo "Select At least one email-id.";
        return view('clientinfo.backtoprev');
    }

}

    public function display1(){

        return view('contactform');
    }

    public function contact($data,$count){
        $input = Input::only('name', 'email', 'msg');

        $validator = Validator::make($input,
            array(
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'msg' => 'required',
            )
        );

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::to('contact')->with('errors', $validator->messages());
        } else { 


            Mail::send('contactemail', $input, function($message) use($data)
            {
                $message->from('your@email.address', 'Your Name');

                $message->to( $data);
            });

            return view('clientinfo.display', compact('data','count'));
        }

    }
```

here is my view "Contactform"

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'ClientsController@contact','method' => 'post','name'=>'f1' , 'id'=>'form_id'))!!}  
    @if(Session::has('errors'))
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            @foreach(Session::get('errors')->all() as $error_message)
                <p>{{ $error_message }}</p>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endif
       //My fields, name & message
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

From the "display" method i'm passing two variables $data and $count to contact method, but after filling form and hitting submit error comes as

**Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\ClientsController::contact()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are corrections that worked for my question.

I used one controller instead of two:

```
    public function showForm(Request $request )
    {
        //Get Content From The Form
        $name = $request->input('name');
        $email = Input::get('agree');
        $message = $request->input('message');

        //Make a Data Array
        $data = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'message' => $message
        );

        //Convert the view into a string
        $emailView = View::make('contactemail')->with('data', $data);
        $contents = (string) $emailView;

        //Store the content on a file with .blad.php extension in the view/email folder
        $myfile = fopen("../resources/views/emails/email.blade.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($myfile, $contents);
        fclose($myfile);

        //Use the create file as view for Mail function and send the email
        Mail::send('emails.email', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
            $message->to( $data['email'], 'Engage')->from('stifan@xyz.com')->subject('A Very Warm Welcome');
        });
//        return view();
    }
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('contactform', 'ClientsController@showForm');
Route::get('/', 'ClientsController@profile');
```

The view **contactemail** has the data to be sent, and the view **email** we are sending through mail function. When the user puts data in the form, that data will get saved in **email.blade.php** because of these lines of code:

```
//Convert the view into a string
        $emailView = View::make('contactemail')->with('data', $data);
        $contents = (string) $emailView;

        //Store the content on a file with .blad.php extension in the view/email folder
        $myfile = fopen("../resources/views/emails/email.blade.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($myfile, $contents);
        fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason :** You're not passing two parameters in your `Mail::` function

**What should you do :**

In the `Mail::` you should pass the two parameters like this

```
Mail::send('contactemail', $input, function($message) use($data, $input)
```

**Update :** You shall try this which would be better than the one that you try to trigger email.

```
Mail::send([], array('UserName' => $UserName, 'Email' => $Email), function($message) use ($UserName, $Email) {
                    $MailBody = 'Hi'.$UserName.'<br>Your HTML Content';
                    $message->setBody($MailBody, 'text/html');
                    $message->to($Email);
                    $message->subject('Subject of Email');
                });
```

Comment: Could you try to send the `input` and other parameters inside the Mail:: function, instead of sending those as parameters.. I mean just hardcoding it ?

Comment: I can send email to only one person after hard-coding, when i first tried i tried it for one person only, then i tried sending mail to array hard-coding it, but again same error. then i passed the variable, as i explained above.

Comment: what do you mean by `mail to array hard-coding`. Sorry i don't understand.. You mean you are trying to run the mail function inside foreach loop ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You shall modify that and use, that would be better solution ;)